# Recording sound from other applications

Tags: audio-recording, gstreamer

Is there a way to record sound from other applications using GStreamer?
I already know how to record from audio sources, but I can't find a way to record from autoaudiosink (that is, record every sound that applications are producing).

EDIT:

I'll accept an answer for valid even if there isn't any way for recording specific applications, but directly from the soundcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application plays via pulseaudio, you can record using pulsesrc device=XX where XXX is the monitor source as the device. Use "pacmd list" and look for the sources: to figure the name.

Comment: Yes, this works. But the result is a really low-quality record (I'm using pulsesrc device=alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo ! audioconvert ! lame bitrate=320 ! filesink ). Also, as you said, this only works with PA. Is there any other way I could record everything, no matter what sound system is installed?

Comment: You can do the same using alsa, but I can't give you the details from the top of my head. I'd discuss the quility in irc with pulseaudio/gstreamer people, I don't see why the quality would be bad.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just one more question, do you know any way for recording from Windows? Maybe I could add this to my application in the future.